# Extract strings from AVR ihex file

Tags: avr-gcc, objdump

I'm using avr-gcc to produce an elf file and later

```
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom main.elf main.hex
```

to create a hex file for programming. How can I extract all strings from the generated hex file? I've tried

```
avr-objdump -j .sec1 -D -m avr5 main.hex
```

But this doesn't show any string.

Background: The .hex file is stored on a separate medium without .elf and I want to check a version string before programming with avrdude

Comment: You can use ELF with avrdude, no need for iHex in the first place. iHex is a "dumb" format with no section or symbol information whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the date is a string like "Sep 10 2020", you can extract it from the ihex file by interpreting the data bytes as a stream of characters, selecting printable strings in this stream (delimited by NUL bytes) and matching them against the date format of your choice. Below is the awk executable script that does that if called with -vout=date option, and does other useful things otherwise

```
#!/bin/awk -f
# dump Intel hex format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_HEX
# several output formats are possible
#  normal       is the default hexdump style
#  date         attempts to extract a single date encoded in the binary
#  string/ascii display nonempty strings of printable/ascii characters
#  size         returns the total number of DAT bytes (code)
BEGIN {
    types[0]="DAT"     # Data
    types[1]="EOF"     # End Of File
    types[2]="ESA"     # Extended Segment Address
    types[3]="SSA"     # Start Segment Address
    types[4]="ELA"     # Extended Linear Address
    types[5]="SLA"     # Start Linear Address
    if(!length(out))
    out="normal";  # output format (string,ascii,normal,date,size)
    if(!length(dateform))
    dateform="(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9]+ [0-9]+"
    maxbytes=255       # avoid long strings
    pcnt=nl=0;
    size=0;
}
{
    sub(/^.*:/,"");    # remove the start code byte(s) of the record
    sub(/\r$/,"");     # remove the CR at the end (if terminated by CR+LF)
    patsplit($0,s,"[[:xdigit:]]{2}");
    bytes=s[1];        # byte count
    if(length(s)-5 != strtonum("0x" bytes))
    printf("BYTE COUNT ERROR %i for record " NR " with %s %s bytes and full length of %i bytes\n",
           length(s)-5,strtonum("0x" bytes),type,length(s)) > "/dev/stderr";
    address=s[2] s[3]; # memory location
    type=types[strtonum("0x" s[4])];  # meaning of the data field
    csum=s[length(s)]; # checksum byte at the end
    c=0;               # check record validity
    for (i = 1; i <= length(s); i++) {
    # printf("%02x+%s=", c,s[i]);
    c+=strtonum("0x" s[i]);
    c=and(c,0xFF);
    }
    if(c)
    printf("CHECKSUM ERROR %02x for record " NR " with %s %s bytes and checksum %s\n",
           c,strtonum("0x" bytes),type,csum) > "/dev/stderr";
    sub(/^[[:xdigit:]]{8}/,"");  # remove byte count, address, and type bytes
    sub(/[[:xdigit:]]{2}$/,"");  # remove the checksum endbyte
    if(length(s)-5 != length($0)/2)
    printf("LENGTH ERROR %i for record " NR " with %s %s bytes and full length of %i bytes\n",
           length(s)-5,strtonum("0x" bytes),type,length($0)) > "/dev/stderr";
    switch (out) {
    case "date":
    if(NR==1) d="";
    for (i = 5; i < length(s); i++) {
        if(length(p)>=maxbytes) p=""; # truncate long strings
        p=sprintf("%c",strtonum("0x" s[i]));
        if(p~/[\x00-\x7F]/ && p~/[[:print:]]/) d=d p;
        if(p=="\0") {
        # /(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) [0-9]+ [0-9]+/
        if(length(d) && match(d,dateform)) {
            printf("%s\n",d);
            exit; # assuming there's only one date ...
        }
        d="";
        }
    }
    break;
    case "ascii":
    for (i = 5; i < length(s); i++) {
        p=sprintf("%c",strtonum("0x" s[i]));
        if(p~/[\x00-\x7F]/ && p~/[[:print:]]/) {printf("%s",p); pcnt++};
        if(p=="\0") {
        if(pcnt) printf("\n"); nl++; pcnt=0;
        }
    }
    break;
    case "string":
    for (i = 5; i < length(s); i++) {
        p=sprintf("%c",strtonum("0x" s[i]));
        if(p~/[[:print:]]/) {printf("%s",p); pcnt++};
        if(p=="\0") {
        if(pcnt) printf("\n"); nl++; pcnt=0;
        }
    }
    break;
    case "normal":
    default:
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s ", address, bytes, type, $0, csum);
    for (i = 5; i < length(s); i++) {
        p=sprintf("%c",strtonum("0x" s[i]));
        printf("%s",p~/[[:print:]]/?p:".");
    }
    printf("\n");
    case "size":
    if(type==types[0]) size+=bytes;
    }
}

END{
    switch (out) {
    case "size":
    printf("%i\n",size);
    break;
    case "normal":
    printf("%i data bytes\n",size);
    default:
    }
}
```